# The most efficient way to go through a list and check all of them in a post request

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to come up with the best solution for going through a list of strings and performing a `POST` request with each one of them.

My previous attempt was to make a `Queue<String>` of the strings `200` or more threads and each thread had a task to `Dequeue` a string from the list and perform the task, which performed worse than I expected.

What I'm doing wrong here?

My code:

```
class Checker
    {
        public Queue<string> pins;

        public Checker()
        {
            pins = GetPins();
            StartThreads(1000);
        }

        public void StartThreads(int threadsCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Threads");

            for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(Printer);
                thread.Name = String.Format("Thread Number ({0})", n);
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        public Queue<string> GetPins()
        {
            Queue<string> numbers = new Queue<string>();

            for (int n = 0; n < 100000; n++)
            {
                numbers.Enqueue(n.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Got Pins");

            return numbers;
        }

        void Printer()
        {
            while (pins.Count > 0)
            {
                var num = pins.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", num, Thread.CurrentThread.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I generate 100.000 5 digits long pins and perform a task (output them through console) and assuming i have 1000 threads, it has to be incredibly fast, which is not.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and anything I can improve. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue is not a thread-safe collection. See [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1)

Your `StartTheads()` method does not use the `threadsCount` arg and therefore only starting 200 threads.

You also need to be careful with threads. Consider using `Task`s or `ThreadPool` instead. IIRC, This will let your app decide how many threads it needs depending on the task count.

Comment: Ah, yeah I noticed that. I get what's wrong now. But, do you have any better ideas in mind?

What's the fastest way I can perform these post requests?

Comment: If the length of "pins" is known, then you could use a list and divide the work up between tasks. 
Task1: 1-50
Task2: 51-100
etc...
If not, then consider using async and create a new task to handle when new pins are received in your queue.